# Passing the correct value from var

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

need to incremet value in order to get the total of all calls on the same function

```
from tkinter import ttk, Tk
root = Tk()

global gen_reprow,x
gen_reprow=8
x=0

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)

def printd(gena):
    print(gena)


def ger_but(vv):
    for x in range(vv):
        ttk.Button(mainframe, width="15", text=gen_reprow, command=lambda gen=gen_reprow: printd(gen)).grid(column=0, row=x, padx=1, pady=15)
        x += 1
        gen_reprow += 1



ger_but(9) # this needs to print 8 to 15
ger_but(5) # this needs to print 16 to 19

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

in this example it i need it to print 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 buttons and depending on the button i select it should print the number he is

range is just and example, my real code is 600 lines, too big to put here, but, basicly, i have a function that is call several times and what i need is to have a var that increments each time, because that function creates a button that calls another function were the number is used.

thats why i call the same function 2 times in the example and try to print the number of times it was called.

the range is because that same function has a loop that some times run like 10 times other 5, or 8 times.

thats why my example.

```
def ger_but(vv):

    for x in range(vv):

        #this button always set the gen 8 and i need it to set the correnpondent number depending on the number gen_reprow is when its generated

        ttk.Button(mainframe, width="15", text=gen_reprow, command=lambda gen=gen_reprow: printd(gen)).grid(column=0, row=x, padx=1, pady=15)

        x += 1

        print(gen_reprow)#this prints fine 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 etc...

        gen_reprow += 1
```

Comment: Can you explain you intention more clearly. What is the logic behind passing 9 and printing 8 to 15?

Comment: i just need to define gen_reprow and increse it by one on each run and every button that is generated send the value of gen_reprow at the moment that its generated

Comment: First you need to declare `gen_reprow` and `x` as global variables inside `ger_but()`.  Then add `print(gen_reprow)` before `ttk.Button(...)` inside `ger_but()`.  Also use `for i in range(vv)` instead of `for x in range(vv)`.

Comment: that didnt make it, please checck the update on the post. thanks

Comment: Please read my comment carefully, I said "declare `gen_reprow` and `x` as global variables _*inside `ger_buf()`*_".  Also use `for i in range(vv)` instead of `for x in range(vv)`.